# How do I split a multi-page tif file?

Tags: split, libtiff

I have big 100+ page tif files and would like to be able to split it at a specified page.

there are excellent tools for doing this with pdfs. I'm looking for something similar for tif images, both GUI and command line solutions.

Comment: And if someone needs to split a double page `.tif` image, use `convert a.tif -crop 50%x100% a%d.tif`. ([Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169534/402870))

Answer (score 5):

The `convert` command from `imagemagick` can probably do what you need. I think this should work:

```
convert a.tif -scene 1 a%d.tif
```

You can also try googling "imagemagick tif multipage convert" to get some more information.

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23053

As for a GUI solution, I'd try opening the file with GIMP, it may be smart enough to open each page in a separate window, then you can export each of them to a separate file.